# Pdfbox not drawing text in specific file only

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I  use   PDFBox 1.8.8 and try to add new  text  to existing  pdf  file. The  problem is  that  text  added  by  me  is  looking compressed for  this  specific  pdf

[original pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/foeb9raub20lbnx/1.pdf?dl=0)  (i  think  this   file  is  source  of  problem)

(it  is  working  for  other pdfs).

[image of problem with explanation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r7hwq4d1i5yuxz/2014-12-23-11-04-14-5937500.png?dl=0)

It  was  not  shown  in  all  originally  but  i fixed  problem with  this  commend (set font display  mode)

```
content.appendRawCommands("0 Tr ");
```

I  was  working  with  pdf  matrix   and  checked almost  everything ...  and  do not  see  way  how  may  i fix  the  problem...

```
content.setTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

questions:

1) is  there are  any  way  to  force  pdfbox  to use  normal  font  settings  and  ignore  current  options  of  font  on page

2) is  there any  way  to  read  current  font  settings and  maybe  play  with  content.setTextMatrix (with height  and  width)

3) what  mode  was  used  in my pdf to  archive  such  kind  transformation ...

my  code

```
private static void writePdfBoxStamp(PDDocument document, int page,
        float topLeftX, float topLeftY, float width, float height,
        String text, float  itemFontSize, int[] color, int rotation) throws IOException {

    PDPage pdfPage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(page);
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdfPage, true, true);


    // COSDictionary pageFonts = pdfPage.getResources().getCOSDictionary();


    //border draw
    float lineWidth = 2;

    float bottomLeftX = topLeftX;
    float bottomLeftY = topLeftY - height;
    float topRightX = topLeftX + width;
    float topRightY = topLeftY;

    float radius = 10;

    content.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
    content.setStrokingColor(new Color(color[0], color[1], color[2]));


    content.setNonStrokingColor(new Color(color[0], color[1], color[2]));

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    int fontSize = (int) itemFontSize;


    float linesHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox()
            .getHeight()
            / 1000 * fontSize;
    float txtLineWidth = font.getStringWidth(text)
            / 1000 * fontSize;

    content.setFont(font, fontSize);

    content.beginText();

    content.setFont(font, fontSize);

    float  posTextX = topLeftX + (width-txtLineWidth)/2;
    float  posTextY = topLeftY  - height/2 - linesHeight/2 + lineWidth;



    if (rotation > 0) {
        int  step = 0;
        // clockwise rotation
        if (rotation == 90) {
            step = 6;
            posTextX = topLeftX + (width + linesHeight)/2 - lineWidth;
            posTextY = topLeftY - (height + txtLineWidth)/2;
        }
        if (rotation == 270) {
            step = -6;
            posTextX = topLeftX + (width - linesHeight/2)/2;
            posTextY = topLeftY - (height - txtLineWidth)/2;
        }
        content.setTextRotation(-step*Math.PI*0.25, posTextX, posTextY);

    } else {
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(posTextX,posTextY);

    }

    content.appendRawCommands("0 Tr "); //set normal text procession

    content.drawString(text);


    content.endText();

    content.stroke();


    content.close();
}
```

Comment: also there  are  link  on    [pdfbox  generated  file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4e5ozksm5ycv7v2/2.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: You can edit your question to include the link there, some people don't read comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your result PDF with PDFDebugger, it has two streams in a stream array for the page, the 2nd stream is the "approved" thing. So what you can do is to enclose the original stream in q....Q to save and restore the settings. I tried it by editing in the PDF with NOTEPAD++ (I first decompressed it with the WriteDecodedDoc command line utility).

There are other strategies that are possibly better than my response, e.g. LayerUtility, or using a transparent image instead (RubberStampWithImage example).

Update:
I see you asked the same question on JIRA, the answer by Andreas is also good:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2581

Comment: Andreas' answer especially is easiest to use in an application.

Comment: Answer  of  Andreas is  working! thank  you   all  for  help!